# iTunes Backup did i lose my backup?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore

okay so basically I deleted whatsapp and the whatsapp backup available on iCloud but before doing that I backed everything up on my itunes pc 
when i reinstalled whatsapp they said that there was no backup available to restore 
so I connected my iPhone to itunes to restore and it said there wasnt enough space, I started deleting apps and pics while downloading the newest update. 
I thought that during the update it will restore everything automatically but it showed backing up message again and here I freaked out because it will over write my old backup that had the whatsapp messages on it.
Now i tried mulitple times to do a restore and it says that the backup is corrupted! 
Does that mean my whatsapp backup is lost? I tried third party apps for extracation and they didnt work
please help im stuck

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted the WhatsApp backup in iCloud and the backup you had in iTunes is corrupted, then your WhatsApp history is gone.

PS: Unless you have made a Windows backup between the moment you made the last good backup in iTunes and the moment it got corrupted, but based on your description this seems unlikely.

Comment: I actually didn’t create a backup, any idea why a backup got corrupted? Or how I can fix it?

Comment: @Megahkiin You've mentioned that you've tried third-party apps, what exactly happened? p.s. iMazing allows a restore of a single app, have you tried that? May work even with a corrupted backup I guess, if corruption is not in WhatsApp files. Should work in trial, so nothing to lose.

Comment: I have tried dr.fone and even paid for restoring license but the app keeps crashing and I managed to restore one chat only to PC not to the phone. I need it on my phone. I will try iMazing and see how it works